# Falling toward a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime

Suppose that there is a body with negligible mass at a distance $r_1$ with no starting velocity from a black hole's centre  and we observe it until it reaches a distance $r_2$ from the black hole's centre. $r_2$ is outside the Schwarzschild radius.

How do I get the proper time for the body , and how do I get amount of time that is needed to this travel if the reference frame which I observe it is  in a ''safe distance'' from the black hole?

Comment: The proper time is just the invariant interval divided by $c$. Plug in the Schwarzschild metric and your worldline.

Comment: This question shows no research effort

Answer (score 3):

I assume that $r_1$ and $r_2$ are radial coordinates from the Schwarzschild geometry, in which the metric outside the black hole is

$$ ds^2 = - \left( 1 - \frac{2 M}{r} \right) dt^2 + \left( 1 - \frac{2 M}{r} \right)^{-1} dr^2 + r^2 d\Omega^2. $$

The particle starts from rest at $r = r_1$, and its four-velocity is

$$ u^\mu = \left( \frac{dt}{d\tau}, 0, 0, 0 \right). $$

$u^t$ can be found from the normalization of the four-velocity:

$$ g_{\mu \nu} u^\mu u^\nu = -1 $$

hence

$$ u^t = \frac{dt}{d\tau} = \left( 1 - \frac{2 M}{r_1} \right)^{-1/2}. $$

Now, because the metric is independent of $t$, we have a conserved energy:

$$ e = \left( 1 - \frac{2M}{r} \right) \frac{dt}{d\tau}. $$

Evaluate this constant of the motion at $r=r_1$ using our result for $dt/d\tau$ found using the four-velocity:

$$ e = \left. \left( 1 - \frac{2M}{r} \right) \frac{dt}{d\tau} \right|_{r=r_1} = \left( 1 - \frac{2 M}{r_1} \right)^{1/2}. $$

Therefore, for any $r$, we have

$$ \frac{dt}{d\tau} = \frac{\sqrt{1 - 2M/r_1}}{1 - 2M/r}. $$

Now, let us consider the four-velocity as the particle undergoes a radial plunge. We have already found the first component, and the last two components are zero, so

$$ u^\mu = \left( \frac{\sqrt{1 - 2M/r_1}}{1 - 2M/r}, \frac{dr}{d\tau}, 0, 0 \right). $$

The normalization of the four-velocity implies an equation for $dr/d\tau$:

$$ \left( 1 - \frac{2M}{r} \right)^{-1} \left( -\left(1 - \frac{2M}{r_1} \right) + \left( \frac{dr}{d\tau} \right)^2 \right) = -1, $$

which simplifies to

$$ \left( \frac{dr}{d\tau} \right)^2 = 2 M \left( \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_1} \right). $$

This equation can be separated:

$$ \left( \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_1} \right)^{-1/2} dr = - \sqrt{2M} d\tau $$

where we have chosen the negative square root because the radius is decreasing with time. In order to integrate the left side, change coordinates to $u = 1/r$, giving the following result:

$$ \begin{align} \int \left( \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_1} \right)^{-1/2} dr &= -\int \frac{1}{u^2 \sqrt{u-u_1}} du \\ &= -\frac{\sqrt{u - u_1}}{u u_1} - \frac{1}{u_1^{3/2}} \tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{u - u_1}{u_1}} \right) \\ &= -r r_1 \sqrt{ \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_1}} - r_1^{3/2} \tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{ \frac{r_1 - r}{r}} \right) \end{align} $$

Now we evaluate the integral between the limits $r_1$ and $r$, which changes nothing because the expression above evaluated at $r_1$ is $0$:

$$ \int_{r_1}^r \left( \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_1} \right)^{-1/2} dr = -r r_1 \sqrt{ \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_1}} - r_1^{3/2} \tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{ \frac{r_1 - r}{r}} \right). $$

Finally this is equal to

$$ -\int_0^\tau \sqrt{2M} d\tau = -\tau \sqrt{2M} $$

where we have assumed that the proper time starts at $0$ when $r = r_1$. We now have an equation that can be taken to give $\tau$ as a function of $r$:

$$ \tau(r) \sqrt{2M} = r r_1 \sqrt{ \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_1}} + r_1^{3/2} \tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{ \frac{r_1 - r}{r}} \right). $$

Evaluating at $r=r_2$ gives the desired result for the proper time of the object as it falls from $r=r_1$ to $r=r_2$:

$$ \boxed{ \tau(r_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2M}} \left( r_1 r_2 \sqrt{ \frac{1}{r_2} - \frac{1}{r_1}} + r_1^{3/2} \tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{ \frac{r_1 - r_2}{r_2}} \right) \right) .} $$

To compute how long this takes measured in the Schwarzschild time $t$, which is the time observed by a distant viewer, we calculate

$$ \frac{dt}{dr} = \frac{dt}{d\tau} \frac{d\tau}{dr} = -\frac{\sqrt{1 - 2M/r_1}}{1 - 2M/r} \left( 2 M \left( \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_1} \right) \right)^{-1/2}. $$

Again, separate and integrate. We get:

$$ \begin{align} \int \left( \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_1} \right)^{-1/2} \left( 1 - \frac{2M}{r} \right)^{-1} dr &= -\int \frac{1}{u^2 (1-2Mu) \sqrt{u-u_1}} du \\ &= -\frac{\sqrt{u - u_1}}{u u_1} - \frac{1+4Mu_1}{u_1^{3/2}} \tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{u - u_1}{u_1}} \right) \\ &\quad - \frac{4M^{3/2}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} - M u_1 }} \tanh^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{2M(u-u_1)}{1-2Mu_1}} \right) \\ &= -r r_1 \sqrt{ \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_1}} - r_1^{3/2} \left(1+\frac{4M}{r_1}\right) \tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{ \frac{r_1 - r}{r}} \right) \\ &\quad - \frac{4M^{3/2}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{M}{r_1} }} \tanh^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{2M(1/r-1/r_1)}{1-2M/r_1}} \right)\end{align} $$

Following the same steps above, this gives the final result:

$$ \boxed{ t(r_2) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2M} - \frac{1}{r_1}} \left( r_1 r_2 \sqrt{ \frac{1}{r_2} - \frac{1}{r_1}} + r_1^{3/2} \left(1+\frac{4M}{r_1}\right) \tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{ \frac{r_1 - r_2}{r_2}} \right) \\ + \frac{4M^{3/2}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{M}{r_1} }} \tanh^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{M(r_1 - r_2)}{r_1 r_2 \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{M}{r_1} \right)}} \right) \right). } $$

Notice that the $\tanh^{-1}$ diverges as $r_2 \rightarrow 2M$. Therefore the distant observer never sees the object reach the event horizon. However, the expression for $\tau$ has no divergent $\tanh^{-1}$ term, so the object will reach the event horizon in finite proper time.

Answer (score 2):

*This is a simplified answer that makes one approximation (distant initial point) to get nicer formulas and clarify the big picture of the calculation. To see the precise final formulas (without approximation) and all the details, see the answer by jc315.*

The trajectory of the body in free fall around a black hole is described by a geodesic in the Schwarzchild solution. In the case that there is no initial speed, the body follows a **radial geodesic** (along which $d\phi,d\theta=0$). Schwarzchild's metric then gives the condition

\begin{equation}
  1=\left(1-\frac{R}{r}\right)\dot{t}^2 -
    \left(1-\frac{R}{r}\right)^{-1}\dot{r}^2,
\end{equation}

denoting derivatives with respect to $\tau$ as dots. The geodesic equation is the differential equation that has to be imposed over a trajectory $x(\tau)$ to be a geodesic. It is

\begin{equation}
  \ddot{x}^\mu+\Gamma^\mu _{\nu\rho}\dot{x}^\nu\dot{x}^\rho = 0,
\end{equation}

where $\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\rho}$ are the Christoffel symbols. For $\mu=0$ the equation is $\ddot{t}+R/r^2(1-R/r)^{-1}\dot{t}\dot{r}=0$, which can be integrated by parts to get $\dot{t}=k\,(1-R/r)^{-1}$. To compute the constant $k$ notice that being at rest at the beginning and using the metric: $1=(1-R/r_1)\,\dot{t}^2_1$, so $k=(1-R/r_1)^{1/2}$. Making the approximation that the initial point $r_1$ is far away, we get $k=1$. Substituting into the first equation and integrating by parts gives

> \begin{equation}
>   \Delta\tau = \int_{r_1}^{r_2}\sqrt{\frac{R}{r}}dr =
>   \frac{2}{3\sqrt{R}}\left(r_2^{3/2}-r_1^{3/2}\right).
> \end{equation}

That is the **proper time** for the body elapsed from the beginning at $r_1$ to the end at $r_2$.

---

Now, for an observer at a "safe distance", meaning at constant $r=r_{obs}\gg R$, time is given by $d\tau_{obs}=(1-R/r_{obs})\,dt\simeq dt$. So we need to compute the elapsed $t$ for the body to go from $r_1$ to $r_2$. Substituting $\dot{t}=dt/dr\,\left(d\tau/dr\right)^{-1}$ and the expression for $d\tau/dr$ obtained for the previous solution $\Delta\tau(r)$ in the equation $\dot{t}=(1-R/r)^{-1}$ we get

\begin{equation}
  \frac{dt}{dr} = \frac{\sqrt{r}}{\sqrt{R}\left(1-\frac{R}{r}\right)},
\end{equation}

and integrating by parts the **time elapsed for the distant observer** is obtained:

> \begin{equation}
>   \Delta t = \left[
>     \frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{r^{3/2}}{R^{1/2}}+R^{1/2}r^{1/2}\right)
>     - 3 R^{3/2}\operatorname{arctanh}\sqrt{\frac{r}{R}} 
>   \right]^{r_2}_{r_1}
> \end{equation}

Comment: You calculate that $dt/d\tau = (1-R/r)^{-1}$. However I calculated that $dt/d\tau = (1-R/r)^{-1} \sqrt{1-R/r_1}$. Which of us has made a mistake?

Comment: I claim that when $r=r_1$ and the object is at rest, we should have that $\dot{t}$ reduces to $(1-R/r_1)^{-1/2}$. See, for example, _Gravity_ by Hartle, page 190, which derives this result.

Comment: You're totally right. I have edited muy answer to fix it

Comment: Okay cool, I wanted to make sure. I see how what you did works as an approximation for large $r_1$. Certainly this makes the equations a bit cleaner!